# WPF Drag and Drop - Get original source info from DragEventArgs

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, drag-and-drop

I am trying write Drag and Drop functionality using `MVVM` which will allow me to drag `PersonModel` objects from one `ListView` to another.

This is almost working but I need to be able to get the ItemsSource of the source ListView from the DragEventArgs which I cant figure out how to do.

```
private void OnHandleDrop(DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data != null && e.Data.GetDataPresent("myFormat"))
    {
        var person = e.Data.GetData("myFormat") as PersonModel;
        //Gets the ItemsSource of the source ListView
        ..

        //Gets the ItemsSource of the target ListView and Adds the person to it
        ((ObservableCollection<PersonModel>)(((ListView)e.Source).ItemsSource)).Add(person);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: In my drag and drop implementation I've created class DragManager (that is singleton) and added a private field draggingElement. Because only one element can be dragged at time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719013/wpf-dodragdrop-dragsource)

The way to do it is to pass the source ListView into the DragDrow.DoDragDrop method ie.

In the method which handles the PreviewMouseMove for the ListView do-

```
private static void List_MouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        if (e.Source != null)
        {
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop((ListView)e.Source, (ListView)e.Source, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }
}
```

and then in the OnHandleDrop method change the code to

```
private static void OnHandleDrop(DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data != null && e.Data.GetDataPresent("System.Windows.Controls.ListView"))
    {
        //var person = e.Data.GetData("myFormat") as PersonModel;
        //Gets the ItemsSource of the source ListView and removes the person
        var source = e.Data.GetData("System.Windows.Controls.ListView") as ListView;
        if (source != null)
        {
            var person = source.SelectedItem as PersonModel;
            ((ObservableCollection<PersonModel>)source.ItemsSource).Remove(person);

            //Gets the ItemsSource of the target ListView
            ((ObservableCollection<PersonModel>)(((ListView)e.Source).ItemsSource)).Add(person);
        }
    }
}
```