# Drag and drop event. Get the name of the control where the drag originated, whilst inside drop event method

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I am attempting a drag and drop in WPF.

My program allows you to drag coloured labels around the screen, in essence giving you the effect that squares are being dragged and dropped.

Bearing in mind that only the text is dragged rather then the control itself (i.e. not the colour):

What I would like to achieve is that when the drop event fires, I can change the colour of the label which I dragged the text from.
After consulting MSDN I've failed to figure out how to get at the control in question and after plenty of trial and error I'm hoping somebody here can help. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.drageventargs.data(v=vs.110).aspx

Below is a sample of code which works, but the label who's colour I want to change is hard-coded, whereas in reality it could be any one of a number of labels.

```
private void ObjDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
   //testSquare is a hardcoded label
   testSquare.Background = Brushes.LimeGreen;  

   //what I really need is for a variable to detect which label to access each time before I change its colour. So something along the lines of 
    Label myLabel = someCodeToGetTheLabelThatWasDragged;
    myLabel.Background = Brushes.LimeGreen;  

}
```

Hopefully I explained things well enough, thanks in advance.

Comment: `e.OriginalSource` or `e.Source` does not contain the control that originated the drag event?

Comment: e.Source is getting me on the path.
However with the code I have now, it is changing the colour of the destination, or the label in which the 'drop' occurs. 
I'm looking to change the colour of the label where the 'Drag' occurred, but I need this to only happen once the drop itself has occurred.

What would be the ideal way to pass or access the 'dragged' label and it's properties from within the 'drop' event? Or is there a tidier way that comes to mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the [`IDataObject.GetData(Type)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94ckfkxz(v=vs.110).aspx) method to extract the the object in `DragEventArgs.Data` property.  From there, you should be able to access whatever you store in the `IDataObject`.

This is a pretty general answer.  To achieve said answer, that means you'll have to write your own class that implements `IDataObject` which contains the original control/control's name etc., then set the `IDataObject` when drag in initialized.

There may be an alternate solution available.  I would watch what `e.Data` is in your current example, and try to work with that.  If `e.Data` is of type `Label`, through casting, you could access the label that way, e.g. `(e.Data as Label).Background = Brushes.LimeGreen;`.

In a Drag and Drop implementation I've seen, the `IDataObject` contains the `DropTarget` and the `DragSource`, that way you can compare the two and allow/disallow things/types from being dragged and dropped by setting the `Effect`.

Comment: Only got around to looking into this in the last day. It got me on a good start to finding  definitive answer. Cheers man.

Answer (score 1):

This page provides the solution for what i'm looking to do.

[WPF Drag and Drop - Get original source info from DragEventArgs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518856/wpf-drag-and-drop-get-original-source-info-from-drageventargs)

The following code in particular used in the drop event method allowed me to achieve my aim

```
Label lbl = e.Data.GetData("System.Windows.Controls.Label") as Label;
```

After that I could manipulate the source of the drag whatever way I wished.