# DragDrop.DoDrapDrop(): how to use the dragSource

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I want to drop a `Rectangle` on a cell of a `Grid` which holds another `Rectangle`. When I drop it, I want to set the `.Fill` - so the color - of the `Rectangle` in the cell to the same as the one I drop respectively the one I started dragging. And some other important data will be "dragged" as well.

For that I tried to use the DoDragDrop method. As it needs three parameters `DragDrop.DoDragDrop(dragSource, data, DragDropEffects)` I thought I'll have all necessary data. But that's not the case. I don't know how to access the `dragSource` parameter.

So my question is: Is there a way to access it easily with the use of the `DoDragDrop()` method?

Or do I have to start from scratch with a different approach?

**EDIT:**
So this is how I use it:

```
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(dragSource, data, DragDropEffects.Move);
```

Where `dragSource` is the rectangle I want to drag to the cell of the grid.
`data` is a property which holds some information which I want to pass over during the drag&drop.

```
private void Rectangle_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
...
}
```

Here the sender is the object, which fires the event. And from the `e` I can get the `data` with `e.Data.GetData(typeof(PlayerModel))`.

But I also try to get the information of the `dragSource`, so the rectangle which I want to drag - and drop - onto the cell. This is what I don't understand. I give in these two parameters at `DragDrop.DoDragDrop()` but don't have the access to that `dragSource` anymore. I'd like to understand where that parameter went.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obtaining DoDragDrop DragSource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719013/obtaining-dodragdrop-dragsource)

Comment: You don't "access" it, you have to specify it.  Anything goes and it only matters to the drop target.  Which can filter and reject objects that come from the wrong source.  Pretty unlikely you have any need to filter by source since you'd only be interested in rectangles, so passing `this` is good enough.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I saw that one, but was confused with "writing the code" or just using the method.

Comment: @HansPassant I specified every parameter. When I drop the recrangle onto the cell another event is raised and the connected mehod is called. This method takes the `sender` and `DragEventArgs` as parameters. So I thought I could access the `dragSource` parameter from the `DoDragDrop` method here to do something like `targetRect.Fill = dragSource.Fill` and still have the `data` parameter available to use.

Comment: @FredMy I don't understand what that means. Can you restate it?

Comment: Seems you are confusing the DoDragDrop() method (specifies the source and the object to drag) with the Drop event (raised on the target, lets you retrieve the source and the object that you used in the DoDragDrop() call.  There are no "extra" parameters, if necessary declare your own class to add anything extra you need to know in the Drop event handler and pass an object of that class to DoDragDrop().

Comment: @EdPlunkett In the question you linked. Not so important.

Comment: @FredMy Are you handling the drag end as well as the drop end? That's what he's talking about.

Comment: @HansPassant I edited my question and tried to explain a bit more. Could you have a look? I think were not talking about the same, because of the lack of my explanation.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes I do. For both I wrote my own method. I'll try his code.

Comment: @EdPlunkett The code from your link worked! Thank you for that.